# Explanation on induction proof of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-explanation, recursion

I don't understand two key steps of a proof that the following sequence is bounded and monotone:

$$(a_n) \text{ defined recursively} \,, \quad a_1 = 0 \,,  \quad a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n +2}{2}  \,. $$

Can anyone explain either of these two steps in the proof? Thank you very much for any help. [Here is an image of the original exercise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAPC0.png)

**1.** First the proof shows that the sequence $(a_n)$ is bounded:

> Induction basis: $a_0 = 0 < 2$
>
> Induction hypothesis: $a_n < 2,n ∈ N$
>
> Induction step:  $a_{n+1} < 2$
>
> $$a_{n+1} = 0.5a_n+1 <  \frac{2}{2}+1 = 2$$

**First question:** by the induction hypothesis obviously the 2 was inserted as $a_n$. Why is that valid?

**2.** Then the proof shows that $(a_n)$ is monotone:

> $$a_{n+1} - a_n = \frac{a_n+2}{2}-a_n=-\frac{a_n}{2}+1$$
>
> From $a_n < 2$ it follows that $-1 < \frac{-a_n}{2}$.
>
> Hence, $a_{n+1} - a_n > -1 + 1 = 0$.

**Second question:** why does the inequality in the last line hold?

Comment: **Why does it hold?** I suppose the definition of your sequence is $a_{n+1}=a_n/2+1$ with $a_0=0$. Then by induction hypothesis $a_n<2$ was "inserted" (**not** $a_n=2$, so $2$ was **not** inserted as $a_n$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the proof is somewhat confusing to follow because $a_n$ and related symbols can have slightly different (albeit related) meanings depending on the context. Sometimes when I get confused by an argument like that, I introduce ancillary symbols/variables to make clearer to myself which parts of the argument I need to pay most attention to and how they are related. This is what I have done when attempting to answer your questions below.

**Regarding the first question:**

You are right, it would be incorrect to assume that $a_n = 2$, that $a_n$ exactly equals $2$, because the induction hypothesis only says that $a_n < 2$, i.e. that $a_n$ is *some* number less than $2$.

So for any given/fixed $n$, define $x:= a_n$, by the induction hypothesis $x < 2$, and by definition of the sequence $(a_n)$, we have that $a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(x+2)$. Because $x < 2$, it follows that $\frac{1}{2}(x + 2) < \frac{1}{2}(2+2) = 2$.

Does it makes sense explained that way?

**Regarding the second question:**

From the first line, they are saying that $a_{n+1} - a_n = y + 1$, where $y = -\frac{a_n}{2}$. I assume you understood the argument why $y > -1$.

Then because $a_{n+1} - a_n = y +1$, and $y > -1$, we have that $a_{n+1} - a_n > (-1) + 1 = 0$.

Comment: This is so helpful, thank you so much for taking the time!